# Describing duties from a previous job on the resume

Tags: grammar

I've been udpating (and translating) my Linkedin profile and I wonder what is the correct way to describe the tasks from a previous job.

For example:

1. Maintenance, diagnosis and repair of electronic equipment
2. Responsable for maintaining, diagnosing and repairing of electronic equipment

Or:

3. Assemble and test of guitar amplifiers
4. Assembling and testing of guitar amplifiers

Is the "ing" being used correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the standard resume form, even applying to the job you do at this very moment:

- Maintained, diagnosed, and repaired electronic equipment.
- Assembled and tested guitar amplifiers.

An improvement brings home the point of why all those verbs matter:

- Maintained, diagnosed, and repaired electronic equipment **to a customer satisfaction level of 92%.**
- Assembled and tested guitar amplifiers **so that (here is where you fill in an impressive reason, like saving a truckload of money or other exciting, non-technical result.)**

*The big advantage of spelling out the benefits is to drive your selling points home:*

- *You work smart.*
- *You achieve results, rather than just pushing massive amounts of paper around.*
- *You do the work for your readers so they can just drink it all in.*